# How to format number to have n whole and decimal digits?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, rounding

Say I have a float `x` that has a whole part `a` and decimal part `b` i.e. `x = a.b`. How can I format `x` in JavaScript such that it'll have at most `n` digits, as shown below:

```js
const n = 5
format(123.0) == '123'
format(123.01) == '123.01'
format(123.012) == '123.01'
format(0.0123) == '0.0123'
format(0.01234) == '0.0123'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/)

Comment: What should happen when `a > 99999` / `x < 0.00001`?

Comment: @Andreas it should give preference to preserving the whole digits over the decimal digits.

Comment: And you should show your approach or otherwise this is just a "do my homework for me" request

Answer (score 0):

Based on a recently deleted answer that had the logic but didn't really work, I came up with this solution:

```js
const format = (number, digits = 5) => {

  const str = number + ''; // convert to string
  let [integer, decimal] = str.split('.'); // split by dot delimiter

  const integerDigits = integer.length;

  if (integerDigits >= digits) {
    return integer;
  } else {
    let decimalDigits = digits - integerDigits;
    decimal = Number('0.' + decimal.substring(0, decimalDigits)).toString();
    return integer + '.' + decimal.split('.')[1];
  }
}
```